# ¿Mapas en IONIC sin usar google maps?

Tags: typescript, ionic, leaflet

Hola y gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda, Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de IONIC y me he topado de añadir un mapa sin usar google maps, el problema es que no se muy bien por donde empezar ya que no encuentro documentación en la que este bien explicada la implementación de otro mapa, cualquier ayuda, explicación de como hacerlo o documentación es bienvenida.

PD: He conseguido lo siguiente con "leaflet" pero no soy capaz de que se renderize el mapa, marcar sitios ...

[Vista de lo que he conseguido añadir (practicammente nada)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K1vE.png)

EDIT: Me da igual cambiar el proveedor del mapa siempre que no sea google maps

Comment: Yo creo que con mapbox se va a hacer bastante sencillo. Lo he usado en pequeños proyectos y ha dado resultado.

Answer (score 0):

La única que conozco que funciona bastante bien es [Here Technologies](https://developer.here.com/)

Tiene una api REST y es fácilmente implementable en JS asique supongo que también en Ionic.